# List to Dictionary with Group in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following variable:

```
List<Tuple<DataType, String, List<String>>> items;
```

I need to create a `Dictionary<DataType, String[]>` where the `DataType` is the Tuple's Item1 and the `String[]` are all the Tuple's Items 2 for that `DataType`.

So I tried:

```
Dictionary<DataType, String[]> d = items.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

This does not compile.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a good example of something you shouldn't be using a `Tuple` for, but rather a named type.

Comment: When you get a compiler error please include what the error is, and where it occurs.  Don't just say "this does not compile".

Comment: Yes, maybe ... But this is something internal to a class so I didn't want to create to many objects when all I wanted was to save some data ...

Comment: It makes the code quite a bit harder to read/understand, and costs just a minute to add the class, which can be a nested class if need be.  Creating types is not expensive at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dictionary<DataType, String[]> d = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Select(t => t.Item2).ToArray()); //the change is on this line
```

The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` type doesn't have a `Value` member. It has a `Key` property and implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

Comment: Ah, I assumed he wanted the third item, nvm.

Comment: @Servy No problem. Yeah I was confused at first too because he had the third item in the tuple but it wasn't actually relevant to the question.